# xpages : add a button inside a pager on a custom control

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a view panel which contains a view and a pager. I want to add a button on this pager, such as this button to be in line with `Previous` and `Next` controls from the pager.

```
 <xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1" viewStyle="width:100.0%">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:this.facets> 
.................... 
.................
```

The button I want then to transform it into a `Expand All` button for the view panel. In same way, I will have a `Collapse All`.

I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

Put the button and pager in a panel, inside the view facets, and move the xp:key="headerPager" attribute from the pager to the panel, like this:

```
    <xp:viewPanel rows="10" id="viewPanel1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel id="panel1" xp:key="headerPager">
            <xp:button value="hello" id="button1">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><! [CDATA[XSP.alert("hello")]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
            <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next"
                id="pager1" for="viewPanel1">
            </xp:pager>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
```

Comment: I got this error: the content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup

Comment: The button appears but I want them both align in line.

Comment: Btw, even when I run the app on browser, the button appears, in the designer it isn't visible, just the pager.

Comment: If you add `style="float: right;"` to both the button and the pager they should line up as you want. You may need to put the pager first in the panel, depending on where you want the button to be. I presume you corrected the typo in Paul Della-Nebbia's code, there's a space after the exclamation mark that needs to be removed `<![CDATA[...`

Comment: The well formed error likely indicates an unclosed tag in the xml markup ... once you move the button into the headerPager facet it will not show in the Design editor ... the Design editor can be fooled, its whats in the XSP source editor that counts.